# How to implement interface defined in TypeScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using `javascript` to implement `vs code` plugin but have a few problems on using `TreeDataProvider` interface. My plugin only show the root node in the tree view but it doesn't show any children. I read the vscode `tree-view-sample` example and found that it uses typescript to create a class implementing `TreeDataProvider` interface. I wonder how I can do that in `javascript`. Will there be problems if I don't implement it?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is pretty much just JavaScript + types. Just remove all the type annotations from the example code to convert it to JS.

VS Code extensions are run in a node environment so if your code is using `import`/`export`, you will also have to rewrite those to something that node can understand or use `tsc` or babel to down compile the js code